# mongodb how to convert _id to String in JAVA

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am reading mongo collection from java code. When I am trying to read the `_id` value, I am getting the following:

```
{"$oid":"541333629520f6e05b0cb410"}
```

I am reading like: `jsonObject.get("_id")` from java code. I was expecting something like: `"_id" : "541333629520f6e05b0cb410"`

Here I am looking for a way so that I can get the _id as a string in one operation.

So far I have been trying the following:

```
        JSONObject idObj = (JSONObject)JSONObj.get("_id");
        ObjectId objectId = (ObjectId) idObj.get("$oid");
```

Comment: _id is of type ObjectId. ObjectId has toString. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/ObjectId.toString/

Comment: Or just use the `$oid` value.

Comment: Expanding the comment of @Jack : [Reading the API docs](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/org/bson/types/ObjectId.html) usually solves these kind of questions pretty fast.

Answer (score 2):

Workaround this issue using the following snippet:

```
        JSONObject idObj = (JSONObject)obj.get("_id");
        String strID = (String) idObj.get("$oid");
```

May be there are some other way to do this in a better way.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
String objectId = (String) result.get("_id.$oid");
```

Maybe there's better ways to do it. Let me know if it works for you.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

With MongoDb Driver version 3 and using Document object.

```
        Document temp = hwCursor.next();
        temp.getObjectId("_id").toString();
```

or

```
temp.getObjectId("_id").toHexString();
```

Answer (score 0):

> import org.bson.types.ObjectId;
>
> ObjectId idObj = (ObjectId)obj.get("_id");
>
> String id = idObj.toString()

Answer (score 0):

```
BsonObjectId bid = (BsonObjectId) result.get("_id");
String str = bId.getValue.toString();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit your answer to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

`String str_id = JSONObj.getId().asObjectId().getValue().toString())`;